# How to print an index of an int array

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of `int`s, denoted as `int* myInts[100];`

When I try to print the 0<sup>th</sup> index like so,

```
printf("%d\n",myInts[0]);
```

I get the following compiler warning:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an `int` array, declare it as

```
int myInts[100];
```

If you want array of `int *`, print it as

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)myInts[0]);
```

Comment: `int *` means pointer to int and `[100]` means array of size 100. Collectively an array of size 100 containing int pointers.

Comment: how would I initialize all of the indexes in the array to 0?

Comment: `int myInts[100] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

```
int* myInts[100];
```

declares an array of one hundred *pointers* to integers, not one hundred integers as you describe.

You need to use:

```
int myInts[100];
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`int* myInts[100];`
It means array of 100 integer pointer.
`int myInts[100];` 
It means array of 100 integer.

to eliminate warning do like
`printf("%p\n", (void *)myInts[0]);`

Comment: you should remove the `*` in the second declaration to match the text.